# Separate div from heading

Tags: css

I want to separate div with id main from header 40px but don't know how.
Also want div primary and sidebar to stretch to bottom. I managed that setting min-height: 500px also to primary and sidebar div. Is it good that way?

And last question, why my footer is separated from main div?

```
 header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 200px;
   z-index: 100;
 }

 #wrap {
   margin-top: 200px;
 }

 #main {
   width: 60%;
   min-height: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }

   #primary {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 80%;
     float: left;
   }

   #sidebar {
     width: 20%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 80%;
     padding: 20px;
     float: right;
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T78CC/

Comment: Regarding your last question, could you add the css for the footer?

Comment: can you give us html code too

Comment: Could you provide the HTML as well? Or even better, could you set up a JSFiddle?

Comment: i hope you know that position fixed means that the element will remain fixed to the screen nomatter how u scroll the page.

Comment: Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T78CC/

Comment: yes I know about fixed, I'm thinking about header to stay fixed rather than it scroll down with a page.

Answer (score 2):

**I want to separate div with id main from header 40px but don't know how.**

```
#main {
    padding-top:40px;
}
```

**Also want div primary and sidebar to stretch to bottom. I managed that setting min-height: 500px also to primary and sidebar div. Is it good that way?**

It's not a great way since anyone wih a screen over 500px will see it ending there.

**And last qustion, why my footer is seperated from main div?**

Because the p tag has margins by default which is pushing things

Answer (score 0):

...so this is simple as kthornbloom wrote.

```
 padding-top:40px;
```

I also added padding-top before posting a question, but thing that confused me is a green space between heading and contents which is padding itself, so this question was unnecessary, sorry folks and thanks for your help again :)